# Rewrite Wordpress-Post-Url to a new domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns, blogs

Is it possible to rewrite / replace a wordpress-post-url "http://myfirstdomain/special-post" like this: "http://anotherdomain/" ? 
(Whitout installing WP-Multisite)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !oldexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Does this rewrites all post-urls to the new domai?

Comment: e.g. http://mydomain/post1, http://mydomain/post2, http://mydomain/post3 to http://newdomain/